# Checking the value in the dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement

The following are my `r` code. I am trying to check whether the true value `a = 10` is included or in the dataframe. If its included in the dataframe, then I need to compute the length of that data frame otherwise I want to assign the length `0` .

Assume the value I am checking is `10`

```
k1 = c(1,2,3,5,6) 
k2 = c(10,12,13,15,16,18)
```

For example, for the `k1` set i want to get the length `0` whereas for `k2` the length must be `6`

I trying to use the following code to do this work

```
library(tidyverse)
map_lgl(k, `%in%`, x = 10) %>% length
```

Why it is not working for the `k1` dataset?

Comment: What is not working? What does it return as it is now? MCVE please https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @christopherlovell, but for the `k1` also I am getting `5`. I want to have `0` for `k1` dataset since `10` is not included in the set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do this with a simple `ifelse` statement - nothing else required.

```
a <- 10
ifelse(a %in% k2, length(k2), 0)

[1] 0
```

you could wrap in a function and feed the different sets in:

```
my_func <- function(x){
ifelse(a %in% x, length(x), 0)
}

my_func(k2)

[1] 6
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have more K(i) lists (100, for example) and you need to interate with all of then, you can use a loop and store the results in a resume table.

I never saw map_lgl, but we can use the ~hard code~ of R, like:

```
k1 <- c(1,2,3,5,6) 
k2 <- c(10,12,13,15,16,18)  

results <- data.frame()

for(i in 1:2){

  analysis <- get(paste("k",i,sep=""))

  if(10 %in% analysis){
    results[nrow(results)+1, 1] <- paste("k",i,sep="")
    results[nrow(results), 2] <- length(analysis)
  } else{
    results[nrow(results)+1, 1] <- paste("k",i,sep="")
    results[nrow(results), 2] <- 0
  }

}
```

Than we get:

[image]